# psexec parameter is incorrect

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am using psexec to execute a .bat on a system. This will fingerprint the system and return the info back to me. The command I use is:

```
psexec \\server -u username -p password -s -i -c .\fingerprint.bat
```

This works with most of the servers, but some of them won't work with the -i switch. Is there a way to say, if this fails, try to do it again without the -i? I am using powershell to execute the script.

```
$servers = get-content .\input.txt

foreach($server in $servers) {
   psexec \\$server -u username -p password -s -i -c .\fingerprint.bat 
}
```

Comment: never worked with powershell, but there must be some way of capturing the exec code of psexec. e.g. some equivalent of bash's `$!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the $LastExitCode automatic variable.  This gets set when PowerShell invokes an EXE.  Whatever exit code the EXE returns gets put in $LastExitCode.  I'm pretty sure psexec returns 0 for success and anything else means failure e.g.:

```
foreach($server in $servers) {
   psexec \\$server -u username -p password -s -i -c .\fingerprint.bat 
   if ($LastExitCode) {
       psexec \\$server -u username -p password -s -c .\fingerprint.bat 
   }
}
```

This is using a PowerShell trick where `if ($LastExitCode)` will if evaluate to true if $LastExitCode is anything but 0.

Comment: I will be using if($lastExitCode -ne 0) . Thanks very much. Any way to get the the last error message?

Comment: You should be able to catch stderr/stdout output like so: `$res = psexec ... .\fingerprint.bat 2>&1`.